# Grouping using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, grouping

I'm new to regex, Sorry for my noobish question
My problem is i want to group the data on the String

What i want to get is the ff:

1. `a-z` `A-Z` or `a-z` `A-Z` 0-9 (ex: abc, bzc15 but not 1abc or 14bc)
2. `0-9` (ex: 1,23,56 and etc)
3. these operators `+` `*`  `-`  `/`
4. the white space
5. `(` and `)`

I want to group them in an array and preserve their position if possible.

Ex:

```
String test = "a + b + 6";
```

The result should be something like this

```
Array[0] = a
Array[1] = White Space
Array[2] = +
Array[3] = White Space
Array[4] = b
Array[5] = White Space
Array[6] = +
Array[7] = White Space
Array[8] = 6
```

Is this possible? If yes, what pattern should i use? 
Any help will be appriciated

Comment: you can use test.toCharArray()

Comment: Maybe get each element of the character array and convert it to int, then get its representation fron a ANSI chart and output that? Might be easier than regex

Comment: If i use `test.toCharArrary()` i can't group data with something like this `ab + b`

Comment: please see my answer, You will need a parser to accomplish the task you are suggesting, unless you want to force your user to use a whole bunch of extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] array = test.split("((?<=\\S)(?=\\s))|((?<=\\s)(?=\\S))");
```

I deduced that you want to split at the start, or the end, of whitespace. But the regex has to be zero-width, otherwise the whitespace would be consumed. This is achieved by using *look behinds* and *look aheads*, which are zero-width. The reflexes in the look arounds are:

- `\s` means "a whitespace character"
- `\S` means "a non-whitespace character"

Then there's the look arounds:

- `(?<=regex)` asserts that the preceding input matches `regex`
- `(?=regex)` asserts that the following input matches `regex`

Then there's the OR:

- `(regex1)|(regex2)` means "matches either regex1 or regex2"

Comment: Wow you got it bro. But can you explain the pattern to me?

Comment: I didn't expect that the pattern will be this short. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char[] charArr = test.toCharArray();
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "a + b + 6";
    char[] charArr = test.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArr));
}
```

Output:

```
[a,  , +,  , b,  , +,  , 6]
```

Comment: If i use test.toCharArrary() i can't group data with something like this `ab + b`. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here but I think you want to parse mathematical statements, or in other words you are trying to perform  Lexical Analysis - (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)

You might want to consider one of java fully developed lexical analysis / parsere generators for an easy solution, The only one that I have worked with is CUP http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/CUP/ and it is quite easy to use.

Other wise you will need to write some custom parser code.

`String[] array = test.split("((?<=\\S)(?=\\s))|((?<=\\s)(?=\\S))");`
or `char[] charArr = test.toCharArray();`
are inapproriate here since the following are cases where you will have inproperly tokenized results

```
input       Expected Result     Result of bad solution
(2 + 4)     [(,2,+,4,)]         [(2,+,4)]
1+2         [1,+,2]             [1+2]
2 + 14(5)   [2,+,14,(,5,)]      [2,+3,14(5)]
3a          [3,a]               [3a]
abs(5 + 6)  [abs,(,5,+,6,)]     [abs(5,+,6)]

*basicaly anywhere the input does not have an explicit space between token, which    
should be allowed but the other suggested solutions do not support.
```

Comment: I see you have a good point there. But my task is to develop my own Lexical Analyzer so i really can't use a made project. Thanks anyways, i want to vote up your post but why i can't?

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex will do what you want:

```
"((?<=\\d)(?=\\p{Alpha}))|((?<=\\w)(?=\\W))|((?<=\\W)(?=\\w))|((?<=\\W)(?=\\W))"
```

It splits the `String` at the following locations:

- After a digit `[0-9]` and before a letter `[a-zA-Z]`.
- Between a word-character `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` and a non-word character.
- Between two non-word characters.